# Model.prototype.save() no longer accepts a callback

Tags: node.js, json

```
After reviewing and trying other questions and answers on StackOverflow, I continue to have the
following problem. This app is for input an item and push it to database - mongodb, But I meet an
error?
I am trying to make a sales website but I met an error
There are my code
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6ZuA.png)
How can I fix it
I also try 
[Another ways](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OK84.png)
But it doesn't working
I have no other way please help meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
Model.prototype.save() no longer accepts a callback

`this one just example to pass stackoverflow:  "I added a couple of libraries to my package.json file, but now I found out I no longer need them
```

Is there some command line parameter to pass to npm install to tell it to remove no longer needed packages? that is, those packages in node_modules that are no longer in package.json

Or shall I just remove the node_modules folder and run npm install once again... (I was hoping for a smarter solution)"`

Comment: const Items = require("./models/items")
app.get("/category", function (req, res) {
  var item = new Items({
title: "hoa",
    order: 1,
    active: 1,
    item_id:[]
  });
  res.json(item);
  item.save( function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log("error!" + err);
    }
    else{
      console.log("OK");
    }
  });
  console.log(item);

});

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```js
const Items = require("./models/items")

app.get("/category", function (req, res) {
  var item = new Items({
    title: "hoa",
    order: 1,
    active: 1,
    item_id: []
  });
  res.json(item);
  item.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error!" + err);
    } else {
      console.log("OK");
    }
  });
  console.log(item);
});
```